# Playlists for mp3 files in Java using BufferedReader & BufferedWriter

Tags: java, mp3, jfilechooser, playlist

I've been working on a really simple mp3 player in java for some weeks now and I'm wondering if I can do playlist with a `BufferedReader` and `BufferedWriter` method. For example with `JFileChooser` I'd choose song and store its path to file (for example "playlist.txt") and then in while loop (`BufferedReader.available()`) I'd read path and play it. Is this possible? Or Is it better to set `chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled()` to true and work in this direction?

Comment: Umm... So what you want to use the `BufferedReader` for? To read stuff from the `playlist.txt` file?

Comment: Yes to read filepaths (which I'd get them with `JFileChooser`)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the best solution for this would be making a `BufferedReader` over the `FileReader` to read the file. Then you can make `java.io.File` objects and put those into a `java.util.ArrayList`. Then you can get the files easily from from the `ArrayList` and dispose the readers. You can also add an refresh method to refresh the list if needed.

Comment: But doesn't method `getSelectedFiles()` already make an array list?

Comment: I don't know about that, but I mean that you can use this kind of setup to read your `playlist.txt` file and get the files listed there into an arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was use a for loop like this:

```
File playlist = new File("U:\\186Project\\Project\\data");
for(File f : playlist.listFiles()){
  song = minim.loadFile(f.getName(), 2048);
  ......
}
```

I was using Processing to make LEDs light up to the beat of music, if you want to check out the full code out go [here](https://github.com/Pwenzel99/Flash-LEDs-To-Beat-of-Music-Arduino).

This won't let you choose certain songs but it does cycle through them like a playlist. Make sure to change "U:\186Project\Project\data" to whatever directory has all your MP3 files in it.